# WordPress порядок вывода постов

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Здравствуйте! Где и как WP составляет массив всех постов(где находится запрос к бд)? Есть такой код для вывода всех постов:

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php appthemes_before_post(); ?>

    <?php get_template_part('content', APP_POST_TYPE); ?>

    <?php appthemes_after_post(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php appthemes_after_endwhile(); ?>

 <?php else: ?>

   <?php appthemes_loop_else(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Мне необходимо переделать запрос к бд, чтобы поменять порядок вывода постов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте хук `pre_get_posts`. Вот пример с сортировкой по пользовательскому полю и дате:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_order' );
function custom_order( $query )
{
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set('meta_key', 'my-custom-field' );
        $query->set('orderby', array('meta_value' => 'ASC', 'date' => 'DESC'));
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Разумеется, вы можете указать свой способ сортировки. Код необходимо вставить в файл `functions.php` вашей темы.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69114/discussion-between-pyramidhead-and-r-mcreal).

Comment: ответил  вам в  чате